# How to get data when I click on array in javascrpit

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

```
$('.table .detailsButton').on('click',function(event){
        
        let productid = document.querySelectorAll('.reqproid').value;
        
        alert(productid);
        
    });
```

This is my Data on spring

```
<tr th:each="pendingStock,iStat:${listPenddingByID}" name="line_items">
    <td th:text="${pendingStock.reqproid}" hidden name="reqproid" id="reqproid"class="reqproid"></td>
    <td>
        <a style="padding: 10px;" id="detailsButton" class="detailsButton"><i class="ti- pencilalt">View</i></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Example that When I Click oh view after that is show alert reqproid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to associate your `View` button with a specific value that is on the same row with the button, you shouldn't use `document.querySelectorAll('.reqproid')` that will return you all elements of this class on the page.

Here is what you can do instead:

```js
$('.table .detailsButton').on('click', function(event) {
  const row = event.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  const productid = row.querySelector('.reqproid').innerText;
  alert(productid);
});
```

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table class="table">
    <tr th:each="pendingStock,iStat:${listPenddingByID}" name="line_items">
      <td th:text="${pendingStock.reqproid}" hidden name="reqproid" id="reqproid" class="reqproid">1234</td>
      <td>
        <a style="padding: 10px;" id="detailsButton" class="detailsButton"><i class="ti- pencilalt">View</i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if this helps.